# How to make the content of these cards spaced and justified at left side to make the cards even

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

[image]

These are my cards and this is it's CSS code

```
card: {
display: 'flex',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'space-between',
border: 'solid 1px #f0eff2',
paddingRight: '1rem',
},
```

and this is my react js code for the card content

```
<div className={classes.card}>
        <Checkbox />
        <div className={classes.title}>{title}</div>
        <div>{description.substring(0, 70)} ...</div>
        <div>{time}</div>
        <div>
          {favourite ? (
            <BookmarkIcon className={classes.gold} />
          ) : (
            <BookmarkTwoToneIcon />
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <IconButton>
            <MoreIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want the content spaced and justified at left side so that the cards looks the same.

Comment: Please add your html as well so we can reproduce this

Comment: I'm using React I updated my post and added my jsx code

Comment: then make a codesandbox snippet or stackblitz

Comment: I have converted your code to plain html and css and it looks pretty much the same as in the picture. It is maybe problem in the way of applying styles to components.

Comment: I don't want them to look like the picture the two cards' content are not aligned the same because i'm using space-between, I think I will change from flex to grid

Comment: if you want all your elements inside your card to be aligned, you can add a width "fix" width on your element that will vary (title, description).